# Cannot make a legend to barplot function.(in R)

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, legend

I want to solve the problem related to function of `legend()` (in `barplot()`) in R. I'd like to make the first column(연령) a lengend in barplot but I can't separate the first column from the graph as shown below.

How can I solve that problem?

Data:

[image]

Image:

[image]

Comment: If your data is in a ```data frame``` you can make a new data frame from it with only the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your `data.frame` into a matrix.

First - turn the first column into row names of your data frame:

```
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
```

Second - remove the first column:

```
df[,1] <- NULL
```

Third - turn your data frame into a matrix:

```
mat <- data.matrix(df)
```

Fourth - create the plot with the legend:

```
barplot(mat, legend=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem thanks to you!